# For acumatica, how can I sum the values of two grid columns within a FormTab and assign that value to a field that's above the FormTabs area?

Tags: acumatica

In the image below, the three fields in the first red square are the ones that I want a calculated value to be. For example, Actual Income would hold the sum of the two columns at the bottom with the red square (I'm not trying to necessarily grab those two fields for the sum, but they just serve as an example).

So what I'm wondering is how would I go about summing up all the values within those two columns and adding the result to one of the three fields (e.g. Actual Income)?

Any help on this issue would be greatly appreciated :D

[image: Image showing fields I want to manipulate]

The image below shows the details for the column 'Original Budgeted Amount'

[image: Details for the column values]

The image below shows the details for the field 'Actual Income'

[image: Details for the three fields at the top]

Answer (score 4):

#WARNING# After a review of the base code it appears those three header fields are used in the calculation of accumulative table ( financial history ) PMTaskTotal as such I would highly suggest not modifying values.

As an alternative :

One method is to add another field to the child record to hold the summary amount of the two fields wanted, I would then add an additional field to the header to hold the calculated value.

Child record field:

```
        #region CuryAmount
        /// <summary>
        /// The amount that is a summary of your two fields
        /// </summary>
        public abstract class curyAmount : BqlDecimal.Field<curyAmount>
        {
        }
        [PXDefault(TypeCode.Decimal, "0.0")]
        [PXFormula(typeof(Sum<field1, field2>))] //Calculates sum of fields
        [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Summary Field", Required = true)]
        [PXUnboundFormula(typeof(curyAmount), typeof(SumCalc<Header.sumfield>))] //Assigns values to header field
        public virtual decimal? CuryAmount { get; set; }
        #endregion
```

Parent record field :

```
        #region CuryTotalAmount
        /// <summary>
        /// The total amount in the from the summed childrecords.
        /// </summary>
        public abstract class curyTotalAmount : BqlDecimal.Field<curyTotalAmount>
        {
        }
        [PXDefault(TypeCode.Decimal, "0.0")]
        [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Total Amount", Enabled = false)]
        public virtual decimal? CuryTotalAmount { get; set; }
        #endregion
```